# How to put my data into DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I'd like to create a DataGrid, which would show data from my List:

```
public List<HeaderTagControlsPair> HeaderTagControlsPairList = new List<HeaderTagControlsPair>();
```

Here's my class `HeaderTagControlsPair`:

```
public class HeaderTagControlsPair
    {
        public TextBlock HeaderTextBlock = new TextBlock
        {
            Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(10,10,10,10)
        };
        public ComboBox TagComboBox = new ComboBox();
        public RadioButton TimeRadioButton = new RadioButton 
        {
            GroupName = "TimeRadioButtons", 
            HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center 
        };
    }
```

So, I'd like my DataGrid to display each item from my list as a new record. As you can see in my class, each record should have: a textBlock, a ComboBox and a RadioButton.

I tried the following:

```
DataGrid MainDataGrid = new DataGrid();
MainDataGrid.ItemsSource = settings.HeaderTagControlsPairList;
this.Content = MainDataGrid;  //display MainDataGrid in the window
```

Unfortunately I get empty window with no records.

If possible, I'd like to do the whole think from code-behind in C#. I don't really understand XAML. BUT if you think it should be done in XAML - I'll do it.

Comment: You need to define DatagridTemplateColumn to have textbox, combobox or radio button in a DataGridColumn. It doesn't work the way you are doing

Comment: Could you please give me a more detailed answer? I tried many things, but I still didn't find a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things that you will need to do some reading on to make this work the way you want.  MVVM design pattern, `DataGrid` controls, data binding, the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, to name a few.

To start with, you do not bind `Controls` to your `DataGrid`, you will bind data.  Shown below is what the XAML would look like for your `DataGrid` control:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=HeaderTagControlsPairList}"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Header" Binding="{Binding Path=Header}"/>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Tag" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Tags}"/>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding Path=Time}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` should be bound to your list of `HeaderTagControlsPair` objects.  This list needs to be in a class that implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface so that the data will be properly displayed and updated in the `DataGrid`.

The `HeaderTagControlsPair` class itself will look something like this:

```
public class HeaderTagControlsPair
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public List<string> Tags { get; set; }
    public bool Time { get; set; }
}
```

It will contain data, not controls.  The actual controls that will display this data are defined in the `DataGrid` columns in the XAML above.

This example is not complete, as you will need to properly set up and implement the class that contains `HeaderTagControlsPairList`.  That is something that you will need to do some research on so that you can understand how that works.  Doing some reading on the topics I mentioned above will give you the needed background to implement this properly and understand why all the extra steps are needed.

Comment: Thank you. Currently I have a working program, but with Grid instead of DataGrid. Using DataGrid seems to be a lot harder than just using Grid. I'll try to do what you said

Comment: Grid and DataGrid are radically different containers.  Grid is for holding controls; DataGrid is for holding data.